# (python) Using @parameterized lib with declaring a driver?

Tags: python, selenium, parameterized

I'm writing a parameterized UI-tests for creating a new user. Previously I did it with `@pytest.mark.parametrize()`, but now I decided to try [@parameterized](https://github.com/wolever/parameterized) .
What my code looks like:

```
class TestUsers:

    @pytest.mark.usefixtures("open_users_page")
    @pytest.mark.usefixtures("login")
    @parameterized.expand([
        ('username', 'password', 'password_confirm', 'email'),  # test id
```

...
and other parameters.
After that:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("fill_create_user_form")  # where i fill non-parameterized fields
def test_user(self, driver, name, password, password_confirm, email):
    users_page = UsersPage(driver)  # where driver is a geckodriver
    users_page.set_name(name)
    users_page.set_password(password)
    users_page.set_password_conf(passwordConf)
    users_page.set_email(email)
    users_page.click_create_new_user_button()
```

After running this I get the error: `TypeError: test_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'email'`
and we tried to rewrite it like this:

```
def test_user(self, *args, **kwargs)
    print(args, kwargs)
    users_page = UsersPage(driver)
```

-- tests printed the args and went to the next step before going to the next step and using the driver.
I have to note that this test worked:

```
    def test_empty_fields(self, driver):
    """Try to create a new user with empty input fields - an errors should appear"""
    users_page = UsersPage(driver)
    users_page.click_add_user_button()
    users_page.click_create_new_user_button()
    errors = users_page.find_item_errors_on_page()
    errors_count = len(errors)
    assert errors_count == 9
```

So the question is: how can I use `self` and `driver` in this situation?
Or should I just forget about the test class and @parameterized and use old `@pytest.mark.parametrize`? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, so after a couple of days of debugging we understood that when I have a couple of fixtures before the test class, then a couple of fixture in the class itself, some of them returns me the 'driver', then I have this code:

```
@parameterized.expand([
        ("short password", 'username', 'password', 'password', 'email@email.com', '',
         pass_len_errs),
...)
```

- parameterized probably thinks that first argument (which is "short password" - the name of the test) - is the driver itself. So this is probably a conflict of arguments.